# AmazonWS Facebook Login - Passing Token

Tags: android, facebook, amazon-web-services, authentication, token

I'm new in AWS and trying to learn in an application that i've just started. The thing is I'm able to sign in with facebook and get the token(veeery long string). The only thing left is I need to send token to AWS Cognito identitiy pool to mark that login as facebook login. Ok I used this code to send the token but it didn't work.

Map logins = new HashMap();
logins.put("graph.facebook.com", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);

In AWS Console facebook is still 0. What might be the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the logins alone does not let Cognito know what you want - It is a local action.

If you want to use that token, you have to send a request to Cognito, which can be done with either credentialsProvider.getId() if you just want an id, or credentialsProvider.refresh() if you want to get usable credentials.

Either one of these will get you an id that Cognito has linked to facebook.

Comment: I tried that way but no solution. Could you please explain in more details.

logins.put("graph.facebook.com", credentialsProvider_ID_Here); credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
credentialsProvider.refresh();

Comment: So that's the code you're using, not what's above?  What's credentialsProvider_ID_Here? Are you getting any error when calling refresh? What about getId()?

Comment: If calling neither of those after setting the logins map is working, can you update your question to have the specific code that you're using?

Comment: Yes sir. As you mentioned about the thing is; 

So the solution follows like;


`Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
            logins.put("graph.facebook.com", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
            credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);`

After that you need to call **credentialsProvider.refresh(); on AsyncTask**